# Github APi for no of commits

Tags: javascript, api, github

I have called a git-hub no of commits api, it gives the data week wise for a year, i want to sort it as month wise. Is there any alternative way to get no of commits in a month.
How would i achieve it. Pls help to sort it out.
Received following data on api call, i want to sort it month wise & then want to show no.of commits in a month.

```
    {  
   "success":true,
   "data":[  
      {  
         "days":[  
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
         ],
         "total":0,
         "week":1471132800
      },
      {  
         "days":[  
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
         ],
         "total":0,
         "week":1471737600
      },
      {  
         "days":[  
            0,
            0,
            2,
            4,
            0,
            0,
            0
         ],
         "total":6,
         "week":1472342400
      },
      {  
         "days":[  
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
         ],
         "total":0,
         "week":1472947200
      },
      {  
         "days":[  
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
         ],
         "total":0,
         "week":1473552000
      },
      {  
         "days":[  
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
         ],
         "total":0,
         "week":1474156800
      },
      {  
         "days":[  
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
         ],
         "total":0,
         "week":1474761600
      },
      {  
         "days":[  
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
         ],
         "total":0,
         "week":1475366400
      },
      {  
         "days":[  
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
         ]
    }
```

Comment: As per SO guidelines, you need to show your code/efforts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help get you started:

var data = {}; // the data you have from Github

```
var months = {};

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log(data[i]);

  // If we have a week, use it. If we don't, it looks like it's the current week?
  var monthNum = 0;
  if (data[i].week) {
    monthNum = new Date(data[i].week * 1000).getMonth();  
  } else {
    monthNum = new Date().getMonth()
  }

  if (!months[monthNum]) {
    months[monthNum] = [];
  }

  months[monthNum].push(data[i]);
}

console.log(months);
```

Comment: You need var data to be the data array of 52. Try var data = data.json().data?

Comment: Its working.

But there is 1 issue, git starts week from Sunday only. In Aug i have committed on 3rd Aug (Thus) & on 8 Aug(Tue), but it showing total no of commits in Aug is 1 only, Coz it starts week from Sunday.
I want to calculate commits from 1st of every month.

Comment: I want Dates & Days of weeks from the array which is coming after api call

Comment: Have you tried anything since I did this? Please post JSON of what you are looking for. This is really a new question at this point since the initial requirement of grouping things differently was solved as per the ask. What you are looking to do is a lot more work.

Comment: Your last code is working fine, but this is as per new requirement. Json is same as i mentioned in question. I want dates & days of weeks  array.

Comment: A new requirement should be a new question for this that outlines what your goals are: What are you trying to do (mockup of output), what have you tried so far etc. Then myself or someone can assist further with that.

Comment: I tried to use 
new Date().getDay(); insted of getMonth in your previous code, but wont work.

Comment: one of developer help to sort it our with above code, pls see change code.
Now i need help on this 
How can i get current date from array & 5 days earlier. 
eg. if today is Aug 10 it should be Aug 5, Aug 6, Aug 7, Aug 8, Aug 9, Aug 10 & no of commits of each date